# Jquery returns index -1 always

Tags: jquery, indexing, removechild

This is my index code that I use to return the buttons parent div's index:

```
j('#optionform').index( j(this).parent() )
```

I'm trying to find out the DIV index of the button clicked, so I can remove the DIV.

The HTML layout is like so:

```
    <form id="optionform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="s_name" value="s_name"> Survey Name </label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="s_type" value="s_type"> Survey Type </label><br>
                    Filter Results:<br>
    <div id="template" style="display: none;">
                        Column: <select id="fcolumn[]">
                            <option></option>
    <option value="s_name">Survey Name</option>
    <option value="s_type">Survey Type</option>
    </select><br>
                        Filter Type: <select id="ftype[]">
                            <option></option>
                            <option value="=">Equals</option>
                            <option value="LIKE">Like</option>
                        </select><br>
                        Filter content: <input type="text" id="fcontent[]"><br>
    <img src="images/add.png" width="32px" onclick="addTemp(); return false;">
    <img src="images/delete.png" width="32px" onclick="alert(j(this).attr('src')); remTemp(j('#optionform').index( j(this).parent() )); return false;">
                    </div>
<div class="template" style="display: block;">
                        Column: <select id="fcolumn[]">
                            <option></option>
    <option value="s_name">Survey Name</option>
    <option value="s_type">Survey Type</option>
    </select><br>
                        Filter Type: <select id="ftype[]">
                            <option></option>
                            <option value="=">Equals</option>
                            <option value="LIKE">Like</option>
                        </select><br>
                        Filter content: <input type="text" id="fcontent[]"><br>
    <img src="images/add.png" width="32px" onclick="addTemp(); return false;">
    <img src="images/delete.png" width="32px" onclick="alert(j(this).attr('src')); remTemp(j('#optionform').index( j(this).parent() )); return false;">
                    </div>
<div class="template" style="display: block;">
                        Column: <select id="fcolumn[]">
                            <option></option>
    <option value="s_name">Survey Name</option>
    <option value="s_type">Survey Type</option>
    </select><br>
                        Filter Type: <select id="ftype[]">
                            <option></option>
                            <option value="=">Equals</option>
                            <option value="LIKE">Like</option>
                        </select><br>
                        Filter content: <input type="text" id="fcontent[]"><br>
    <img src="images/add.png" width="32px" onclick="addTemp(); return false;">
    <img src="images/delete.png" width="32px" onclick="alert(j(this).attr('src')); remTemp(j('#optionform').index( j(this).parent() )); return false;">
                    </div>
 </form>
```

But it always returns `-1` in the index.

Comment: it returns -1 because `$(this)` isn't in the `$("#optionForm")` collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$(this).parent().index(".template")`, however keep in mind that your first template div has an id instead of a class. is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need the index of the div when you can directly remove the parent of it.

```
j('#optionform').parent().remove();
```

`j('#optionform').parent(`)  will give the Div in which the button is clicked

Comment: Your right :S I feel dumb founded. Probably because I was working way too long on this today and was over complicating it! Thanks.